# How to make a relay ON for few seconds after power goes OFF?

Tags: delay

I want to make relay circuit that can remain ON if power is supplied but as soon power is cut off i want the relay to go OFF after few seconds atleast 10 sec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Providing the circuit that drives the relay electrically disconnects itself when power is removed (i.e. the power gets switched on then the power is removed by a switch), think about using an electrolytic capacitor to sustain the coil current for a few seconds.

A 12 volt relay might have a coil resistance of 1000 ohms and the relay might drop-out when the coil voltage reaches (say) 6 volts. This means the voltage shouldn't fall by more than 6 volts in ten seconds.

That's a \$\dfrac{dv}{dt}\$ of 0.6.

If the current needed to sustain the relay is 6 volts/1000 ohm that is 6 mA hence: -

6 mA = C dV/dt or, C = 10,000 uF.

Comment: Sami,  Keep in mind delay turn on spec. If you want 0.1s turn on that means instead of 10 seconds current will be 10/0.1 or 100x bigger , e.g. 600mA and with full 12 voltage 1.2A surge  if current limited.

Comment: For a 230v relay that I need to keep ON for 1 second, what size/voltage capacitor should I use?

Comment: @tunafish24 please ask this using the main facilities for asking new questions and make sure you link the data sheet for the relay.

Comment: @Andyaka Asked my question here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/698331/keep-a-relay-latched-for-2-3-seconds-using-capacitor

Answer (score 1):

The basic equation for a discharging capacitor with a resistor is:

V2/V1 = 1 - e^(t/RC)

This equation relates the time (t) it takes a cap (value C in farads) to discharge into a resistor (value R in ohms) from an initial voltage of V1 to a lower voltage of V2.  There are five variables in the equation, so you need to know four of them for a unique solution.  From the example above:

- V1 = 12 V
- V2 = 6 V
- t = 10 seconds
- R = 1000 ohms

Solving, C = 14,427 uF.

---

A way to estimate things with less complex math is to use the equation for a constant-current discharge:

ec=it

e x C = i x t

voltage drop times capacitance equals the discharge current times the time.

For this estimation using a constant resistance instead of a constant current, the average voltage on the capacitor is (V1 + V2) / 2, or 9 V.  This gives an average current of 9 mA.

6 x C = 0.009 x 10

Solving, C = 15,000 uF, a 4% error and the closest value to 14,427 uF anyway.  Given the poor tolerance of electrolytic capacitors, I recommend 20,000 or 22,000 uF as a starting value.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't mention your application, it's possible that you don't care how long the relay is on after power is removed.  If "infinite" fits within your spec, you could use the relay's NC (normally closed) contacts, and the switch would close upon loss of power, and stay that way until power is restored.

Answer (score 0):

You will get the maximum dropout time and make it easier to calculate if you put a resistor of the correct value in series with the capacitor. Select a value that causes the relay to drop out when the capacitor gets down to V/e ie 36.788% of the applied voltage (Vmax). The dropout time will be the time constant. T=RC x 10^-6 , where R = Rres + Rrly. The resistor also acts as a surge limiter when power is applied. Copper has a very high temperature coefficient of resistance. I've seen the coil res. rise by as much as 11% from cold to running temp., so it's probably easier to measure the dropout current (Id), then calculate hot res. from running current, using ohm's law so the coil temp. stays constant. If it's significantly different, take the average of hot & cold resistance, then add the extra resistance in series with the capacitor to get dropout current at 36.788% of Vmax. The exact res. is not critical, as dt/dR=0 at the ideal res. so a small variation has negligible effect.

Eg if you use the 12V relay in the question about pickup, dropout times etc. , the coil res. is 720R and min. dropout vol. is 10% rated vol. If this one happens to be 15%, then Id would be 12x.15÷720=2.5mA. If the warm resistance is, say 736R, the average is 728R. Now R=12÷e÷.0025=1,766R  1766-728=1,038R (use 1k). C=t÷Rx10^6=10÷1728x10^6=5,787uF. Use the nearest value above (which will be either 6,800uF or10,000uF).

Answer (score -1):

Time delay relays are what you are looking for.  Try entering "time delay relay" in your favorite search engine. : )

Comment: Don't time delay relays require a stable power source throughout the timing period?

Comment: @AnalogKid  I suppose some do, but certainly not all.

Comment: @MichaelGorsich Can you share link to a time delay relay that doesn't require power source? I tried but couldn't find one