# Keep a relay latched for 2-3 seconds using capacitor

Tags: capacitor, circuit-design, relay

Building a simple prototype to keep the relay latched for a couple of seconds *after power is removed* - so essentially the power to relay acts as the Input signal. This means I have to store energy in a capacitor (to keep the relay latched) and possibly use resistor as well to control current in the circuit. Can you guys please help me figure out C and R values and how the components would link (C would be in parallel with the Relay but not sure about R)?

Important things for me are:

1. Relay should latch as soon as 12V power is applied
2. Capacitor should charge within 500-700ms and be able to keep relay latched for 2-3 seconds.
3. Since I have to charge capacitor quickly, I need to factor in-rush current so as not to damage power supply.

Would really appreciate if you can share the calculations as well, so I can try with different relays and capacitors etc.

The relay i have is Songle 12V (SRD-12VDC-SL-C), Datasheet: http://www.songlerelay.com/Public/Uploads/20161104/581c81ac16e36.pdf

Comment: Why not just use a time-delay relay (delay-off type)?

Comment: why is a capacitor a required component of the solution? ... a battery may me suitable

Comment: Its a standalone circuit, time delay relays require external/constant power source. In this case, the power will be removed altogether but the relay needs to stay energized for a set minimum amount of time (2 - 3 seconds).

Comment: @tunafish24 Not [all](https://shop.industrialemart.com/pdf/AT8P.pdf) [of](https://www.digikey.com/en/htmldatasheets/production/1813378/0/0/1/scerx22aba) [them](https://damapi.marshbellofram.com/uploads/TDT_Spec_Sheet_41fd3c369e.pdf) require external power. It's easier to make an off-delay relay with an external supply, but that's not the only way--these ones either have internal capacitors/batteries for shorter delays, or for longer delays they may make use of clockwork timers.

Comment: Do you want to use a latching relay or just a normal (non-latching) relay that stays energized for a few seconds when power is removed?

Comment: Normal relay that stays energized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solve the standard RC discharge equation for the time constant RC.
$$
\tau=RC=\frac{-t_{\text{dropout}}}{ln\left(\frac{V_{\text{dropout}}}{V_\text{initial}}\right)}
$$

Use the initial coil voltage and the dropout voltage. The relay coil resistance is used for R. The relay inductance will not be significant enough to affect the result.

For the circuit in the diagram, and for the relay in the OP, a 2200μF capacitor should work. The capacitor will charge to 12V less one diode drop. When the capacitor discharges, the initial coil voltage will be 12V less two diode drops.

The relay datasheet will provide values for \$V_{\text{dropout}}\$ and coil resistance.
Choose R1 to limit inrush current.

If the relay drops out at a higher voltage you will need a higher capacitance. For example if the dropout is actually 50%, then a 6800μF capacitor is required.

To include Simon Fitch's comment:
"...to have \$C_1\$ charge within 500ms: \$5R_1C_1≈0.5\$, or \$R_1≈0.1C_1\$. With \$C_1=2mF\$, that makes \$R_1≈50Ω\$, and inrush current will be \$I≈1250=0.24A\$"

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmJrfXm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: See my answer update.

Comment: The magnetic opeation of the relay puts the dropout voltage significantly lower than the pick-up voltage because the relay armature is touching to the electromagnet pole when energized. I would be surprised if the droput voltage of any relay is close to 50%. More likely to be between 10% to 20%. Your range is too wide.@AnalogKid

Comment: Just for OP's information, to have C1 charge within 500ms: \$5R_1C_1\approx 0.5\$, or \$R_1\approx \frac{0.1}{C_1}\$. With \$C_1=2mF\$, that makes \$R_1\approx 50\Omega\$, and inrush current will be \$I\approx \frac{12}{50}=0.24A\$

Comment: What wattage resistor should i use?

Comment: The energy dissipated by \$R_1\$ is about \$0.25 J\$ over \$0.5 s\$. So the average power over that time is about 1/2 W. However the average power for consecutive charging will be a lot smaller. A 1/2 W ( maybe 1/4W if a long time in between.) resistor is sufficient. Check the data sheet to be certain it will handle the peak of 2.9 W.

Answer (score 1):

> after power is removed

Does that mean that the one or both leads of the supply are physically removed (unplugged or with a switch), or that the 12 V source goes to 0 V. If the latter, you will need to add a diode in series with the supply so its output circuits do not add a discharge path for the capacitor.

Three seconds is a long time for a capacitor to power an inductor.  According to the datasheet, the relay is guaranteed to operate at 9 V, so we will assume that once it is on, the relay will stay activated with 9 V on the coil.  This means the relay will drop out when the coil voltage passes through a value somewhere between 9 V and 1.2 V.  That's a very wide window.  The lower the drop out voltage, the smaller the capacitor size needed.

Using the capacitor discharge equation, discharging to 75% in 2 seconds, I get 3600 uF.

If you have access to large-value capacitors, start with 4700 uF.

Charging that to 95% takes three time constants.  With C = 4700 uF, a series charging resistor R works out to be 35 ohms.

Update:

The datasheet is a bit confusing.  What it means is that the relay is guaranteed to pull in at 75% of nominal or more, but can pull in at any voltage below that (all the way down to 0 V!).  The relay is guaranteed to drop out when the coil voltage is 10% of nominal or less, but might drop out at any voltage above that.  Since the relay is guaranteed to operate at 75% of nominal, I took that as the maximum guaranteed dropout voltage.